# How can we implement the "Connect to facebook" option in my site?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Could any one suggest me how to get the facebook login service?Is it free or any payment mode.I would like use this in my site.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about facebook.

However, have you considered using `OpenID` - http://openid.net/

With OpenID your users can use their existing logins in authentication services like Google, Yahoo etc. Also there are instruction on how to use it on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything you'll need in terms of Facebook connect and all that can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/plugins. It's all free.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook developers section provides good documentation about this subject.

Take a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#registration